# Problema de login com senha em MD5

Tags: php, mysql, sql, login, md5

**Form de login:**

```
<form id="1" name="1" action="pass.php" method="post">
<div class="login">

    <input placeholder="Usuário" type="text" id="username" size="25" name="name" /><br>
    <input placeholder="Senha" id="pass" type="password" size="25" name="pass" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="1" value="Login" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="ed_type" value="" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<? echo $redirect;?>" />
</div>
</form>
```

**pass.php**

```
    <?
        session_start();
        $usuario_admin=isset($_SESSION['1x11'])?$_SESSION['1x11']:'';

       include("conf.inc.php");
       include("conectar.php");

  $query="select * from admin where username='".$_POST["name"]."' and pass=MD5('".$_POST["pass"]."')";
      $result=mysql_query($query,$db);
      $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
      $total = mysql_num_rows($result);
      $name=$_POST['name'];
      $pass=$_POST['pass'];
      $ADMIN_USERNAME=$row["username"];
      $ADMIN_PASSWORD=$row["pass"];

      if($total>0){   
          if($name==$ADMIN_USERNAME && $pass==$ADMIN_PASSWORD){
              if($usuario_admin!='') $_SESSION['1x11']="";
              $_SESSION["1x11"] = $name;
              $_SESSION['logedin'] = true;
              $_SESSION["type"] = $row["type"];
              $_SESSION["usrname"] = $name;
              $_SESSION["logid"] = $row["id"];
              header("Location:index2.php");
          }
      } else {
        header("Location:index.php?id=1");
      }
    ?>
```

**PHP para atualizar senha pelo formulário após fazer login:**

```
<?
       include_once("conf.inc.php");
       include("conectar.php");

    $sel="select * from admin where id='".$_SESSION["logid"]."'";
    $ressel=mysql_query($sel);
    $rowsel=mysql_fetch_object($ressel);
    $name=stripslashes($rowsel->username);
    $title=stripslashes($rowsel->pass);



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $title = addslashes($_POST["title"]);
    $sql="update admin set pass=MD5('".$title."') where id='".$_SESSION["logid"]."'";         
    $ressql=mysql_query($sql) or die("Erro ao atualizar a senha!");
    header('location:message.php?msg=55');
}
?>
```

Pessoal, estou com um problema aqui, não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar o login.

Para atualizar a senha após o login ele funciona normalmente e registra no DB como MD5, porém quando faz logout e tenta logar novamente ele não funciona, fala que a senha esta errada.

O que pode esta ocorrendo? Parece que ele não esta convertendo em MD5 ao fazer login...

Answer (score 1):

reparei dois detalhes no seu código:

O primeiro é que ao fazer a verificação da senha você está usando a função md5 do PHP

> $query="select * from admin where username='".$_POST["name"]."' and pass='"**.md5($_POST["pass"]).**"'";

O segundo é que ao fazer a atualização da senha no banco de dados, você está usando a função MD5 fornecida pelo seu banco de dados:

> $sql="update admin set pass=**MD5('$title')** where id='".$_SESSION["logid"]."'";

Na minha opinião, uma boa prática é sempre usar o mesmo método (mesmo que o algoritmo seja o mesmo), então, uma dica é usar ou o método MD5 do banco ou o método do PHP em ambos os casos.

Mas voltando ao seu erro...

Você esqueceu de concatenar a senha para o método de hash, ao atualizar a senha, você está sempre utilizando a string `$title`.

Tente desta forma:

```
$sql="update admin set pass=MD5('".$title."') where id='".$_SESSION["logid"]."'";
```

Comment: Olá Diogo, obrigado pelas dicas! Então, na verdade o problema esta com o arquivo pass.php, pois não consigo fazer login. A alteração de senha funciona normalmente. Eu atualizei para o método MD5 do banco de dados para ambos, fiz a correção da parte que mencionou mas o problema persiste, não faz o login. :/

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com os códigos corretos, conforme mencionou..

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive um problema assim porque o banco estava gerando uppercase e o nodejs no meu caso lowercase na hora de comparar são diferentes: exemplo
c8d11180c956e5b5afc3d1970ce2193e
<>
C8D11180C956E5B5AFC3D1970CE2193E

Comment: Eu verifiquei no banco e ele ta salvando tudo em minusculo. Como posso fazer para saber se ele ta gerando em maiúsculo ao comparar?

Answer (score 1):

Como o colega disse, usar métodos de md5 da linguagem e do banco pode ser que de alguma diferença, apesar de eu achar isso pouco provável.

Sugiro que remova o `MD5(...)` das queries e use esta conversão antes:

> $passwd = md5($senhaDoUsuario);

Usei `$senhaDoUsuario` por você esta usando duas variveis diferentes então substitua pela correspondente, e consecutivamente use na query a variável nova `$passwd`;

Outra coisa este trecho a baixo, troque ele pelo citei a cima.

> $title = addslashes($_POST["title"]);

Pois o `addslashes` pode estar adicionando algum `\` em sua senha onde não deveria, e com a conversão para md5 como citei já vai eliminar SQL Injection **pelo menos nesta variável**.

Comment: Rapaz, fiz o que você falou mas sem sucesso, não funciona de jeito nenhum... ele não faz o login, o que será que pode esta ocorrendo? Se eu remover os MD5, ele faz login normalmente.